# Bing Image Search SDK for Python: Getting 'Permission Denied'

Tags: python-3.x, azure, bing-api

I'm trying to use the example program [provided by Microsoft here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-image-search/image-sdk-python-quickstart) to test out the Bing Image Search Service associated with their Cognitive Service offering on Azure.  I type the code in character by character (of course, using my own API key) and I get the below error message when I execute the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "x.py", line 9, in <module>
image_results = client.images.search(query=search_term)
File "/home/rsbrownjr/anaconda3/envs/ibing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/search/imagesearch/operations/images_operations.py", line 485, in search
raise models.ErrorResponseException(self._deserialize, response)
  azure.cognitiveservices.search.imagesearch.models.error_response_py3.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'PermissionDenied'
```

I know without a doubt that I have the right API key put into the program.  I'm on pricing tier S0 pay-as-you-go but I don't have any other options either.  This has got to have a simple solution.

```py
from azure.cognitiveservices.search.imagesearch import ImageSearchAPI
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

subscription_key = "MY API KEY HERE"
search_term = "canadian rockies"

client = ImageSearchAPI(CognitiveServicesCredentials(subscription_key))

image_results = client.images.search(query=search_term)

if image_results.value:
    first_image_result = image_results.value[0]
    print("Total number of images returned: {}".format(len(image_results.value)))
    print("First image thumbnail url: {}".format(
        first_image_result.thumbnail_url))
    print("First image content url: {}".format(first_image_result.content_url))
else:
    print("No image results returned!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested the code, the code is fine. So you must provided the wrong API key.

[image]

Here is my test key `52c32221ceaa4f388b26a2b85fb79bff`. It is a 7 days free trial key. I got it [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/my-apis/).

[image]

Comment: With your key, the code works like a champ.  What the heck, then?  I'm getting the keys right from the Azure portal!  I thank you so much for enabling me to run a test against that key.  I will definitely check this answer as the correct one but I'd like to leave it open for a short time to see if anyone can provide some additional troubleshooting tips for me.  As I said, I don't know what other key I could provide - it's coming right from the Azure portal ... maybe my pricing tier is the issue?  Shouldn't be, though.  Plus, I'm the owner of the subscription.  Strange.

Comment: As I suspected, it was something simple.  I thought creating a Cognitive Services resource group was enough.  It wasn't.  I had to create a specific Bing Image Search Service.  Going ahead and awarding answer due to nice gesture of letting me use trial API key.

Comment: Thanks to RiverRock - that was the key for me - though it's now called just Bing Search Service